# How to set up an R based service on a web page

Tags: r, web

I would like to provide the following service on a webpage:

- Running an R-script daily which collects publicly available data and does some calculations (I have developed the script already, it needs some additional libs!)
- Posting the updated graphical and numerical/textual output on the webpage

I don't want to run my own computer all the time so a kind of a cloud solution should be employed (I guess?!?).

Do you have any ideas how to accomplish the above ideas?

Comment: There is an entire section in the FAQ on R and web interfaces.

Comment: For hosting, you could use Amazon's EC2 micro-instances.

Comment: @Iterator: I have no experience with EC2 but it should be possible to just run the script every day and fetch the results, right? Using it for the complete hosting might be too expensive, or not?

Comment: @vonjd Amazon offers a scale of service that is actually free.  I've not used it, but it may work out for you.

Comment: @Dirk: ... except that I'm too lazy to provide text for Kurt to update the FAQ with FastRWeb ;)

Comment: I found a project named rApache (www.rapache.net), but not sure about security, neither an appropriate Debian's package.

Comment: What about Shiny? http://shiny.rstudio.com/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may have a look at [FastRWeb](http://rforge.net/FastRWeb) - it serves R scripts as if they were web pages and supports graphics as well as regular output. It uses Rserve which makes it much faster than any solution that involves starting R (such as `R` or `Rscript`). It works on any webserver wither via CGI or PHP.

A script to generate a plot would look like:

```
run <- function(n=100, ...) {
   p <- WebPlot(800, 600)
   n <- as.integer(n)
   plot(rnorm(n), rnorm(n), col=2, pch=19)
   p
}
```

Other solution is [RApache](http://rapache.net/) which embeds R directly into the apache webserver.

**Edit:** And also by Jeff there is now [Rook](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rook/) that uses the embedded R HTTP server (thanks to Joshua for pointing that one out).

You mentioned running it daily - if you don't need online analysis, you can simply generate `html` pages and `png` files with R and send them to your webserver - all in an automated script. There are many R package that facilitate HTML output - just search in the CRAN package list for HTML.

Comment: [Rook](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Rook) is another option and is easier to setup than rApache for simple apps like this, since it uses R's httpd server.

Comment: FastRWeb documentation appears to state that it will not work under Windows (it recommends using an additional Unix server if your webserver is Windows-based).

Comment: It will work (and the doc says that), but using Windows as R webserver  is sort of useless/suicidal in general.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Rscript`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/Rscript.html) and `cat` to print an HTTP response like you would from any [CGI-bin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface). For example, set the content type of the response and then `cat` some HTML, or print a PNG, etc:

```
#!/path/to/Rscript

cat("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
cat("<html>")
cat("<body>")
cat("<p><em>Hello</em>, world!</p>")
v <- round(runif(10)*10, 0)  # sample ten random integers from {0..10}
cat("<p>", v, "</p>")
cat("</body>")
cat("</html>")
```

Comment: Thank you, Alex. You would have to do it on your own computer, right?

Comment: Anywhere where there's a running web server and an installation of R.

Answer (score 2):

On an Apache/PHP box consider a very simple set-up using Rscript.  This approach may be especially relevant if you have a Windows server (as several other options for R servers appear to require Linux).

The following example assumes Apache/PHP under Windows.

WebApp PHP frontend:

```
$GLOBALS["pathRscript"] = '"c:\\Program Files\\R\\R-2.14.1\\bin\\Rscript.exe"';
$GLOBALS["webAppRInterface"] = "c:\\WebApp\\R\\WebAppR.R";

function WebAppR($rExpression) {

    $command = $GLOBALS["pathRscript"] . " " . $GLOBALS["webAppRInterface"] . " " . $rExpression;    
    system($command);
}
```

WebApp R interface (WebAppR.R)

```
## Sink any error messages to an error log file
errorLog <- file("c:/WebApp/R/error.log", open="wt")
sink(errorLog, type="message")

## Do an R call from a string passed from PHP
## Quotes in the string must be sent from PHP using the backquote "`"
eval(parse(text=gsub("`", "'", paste(commandArgs(T), collapse=" "))))
```

From PHP call `WebAppR()` giving R code as a string encased in double quotation marks `"` and replacing all R code quotation marks with backquotes `` "`" ``.  You can `source()` another script in this call, or simply `cat()` the result of some function.  The result will be incorporated in the PHP page.  One important limitation is that use of two types of quotation marks (typically ' and ") is not possible in the same R statement.  If you intend to return HTML, which is full of quotation marks, it is simplest to use a sourced script that will `cat()` the result rather than including HTML in the WebAppR() call.