# How to run R script from HTML webpage

Tags: database, r, csv, d3.js

I have no experience with R language. I have been given some R scripts that my webpage would run. I am developing a web application where the user uploads a file and the contents of file are saved in a database and a basic scatter plot (using php and d3) is produced with patient names and years. The application would let the user to select any 'dot' of the scatterplot for detailed analysis. When the user does a selection, the application should get the respective row from database with all the fields and write them in a csv file. And feed this csv file to a format conversion R script to produce 'new_format.csv'. After format conversion, new_format.csv has to go to another R script that does the main calculations and stores result in a Rdata file.

How do I run R script from my webpage? Where do I save/store the two intermediate csv files produced during the calculations and how do I feed them forward?? And How do I fetch results from Rdata file and save them in database or draw some graphs using them?

BTW as these R scripts are being provided to me, therefore, I am not allowed to change them. And yes, the R script is designed to read a csv file, that is why I want to convert the selected database row to a csv file.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: How about using [Rscript](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/Rscript.html)?

Comment: Have you had a look at [clickme](https://github.com/nachocab/clickme).  This sounds like something it would suitable for. Having said that, from what you describe there is quite a bit of work to be done. The way I read your question is that there will be an application sitting on a server where users upload a file. That file is then passed to R which is server side. R does some magic and then serves up a csv file to the browser.  I'd look at Shiny and RStudio as RockScience suggested.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're asking how to do the data processing on the back-end. If you have R installed on your server, you can use PHP to run commands to execute your R scripts using the `shell_exec()` function. The command to to execute an R script looks like the following:

```
R CMD BATCH "--args 'dataPath/input.dat'" script.R
```

This will produce a script.Rout file with the output or you can have the R script internally output a file with the results. The R script will need to use the following function internally to get the input data file name from the command line:

```
dataFileName <- commandArgs(TRUE)
```

That being said this can be done faster using specialized infrastructure such as [FastRWeb](http://rforge.net/FastRWeb/). Also see [How to set up an R based service on a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174114/how-to-set-up-an-r-based-service-on-a-web-page) for other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

you can start a webserver with R script using at http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/

Comment: The R scripts just do the calculations and I want to use d3js for graphing those calculation results. I am not sure on how to use rstudio to do that.

Comment: maybe you should do some reading on the page I sent you. It is about shiny, not Rstudio.

Comment: There is also [RStudio Server](https://www.rstudio.com/ide/server/) which could be used.

Comment: The question is very specific about executing rscript from html. Shiny is a completely different solution